# Problem inserting new records using INSERT-SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to insert only new records. Based on new UserID or existing UserID and new LicenseState.  Having problems getting my WHERE clause correct.

Here's the sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE #SourceData
(
    UserID  varchar(30),
    LicenseState  varchar(2),
    LicenseNumber  varchar(10),
    LicenseYear  int
)

CREATE TABLE #Person
(
  PersonID  int,
  LastName  varchar(30),
  FirstName  varchar(30),
  DomainAccountName  varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE #License
(
  LicenseID  int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  PersonID  int,
  LicenseState  varchar(2),
  LicenseNumber  varchar(10),
  LicenseYear  int
)

-- Load #SourceData
INSERT INTO #SourceData (UserID, LicenseState, LicenseNumber, LicenseYear)
VALUES ('gwashington', 'CA', '11111', 1999);

INSERT INTO #SourceData (UserID, LicenseState, LicenseNumber, LicenseYear)
VALUES ('gwashington', 'TX', '9999', 2001);

INSERT INTO #SourceData (UserID, LicenseState, LicenseNumber, LicenseYear)
VALUES ('jadams', 'CA', '22222', 2000);

INSERT INTO #SourceData (UserID, LicenseState, LicenseNumber, LicenseYear)
VALUES ('tjefferson', 'TX', '44444', 2002);

INSERT INTO #SourceData (UserID, LicenseState, LicenseNumber, LicenseYear)
VALUES ('alincoln', 'IL', '55555', 2012);

-- Load #Person
INSERT INTO #Person (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, DomainAccountName)
VALUES (1, 'Washington', 'George', 'gwashington');

INSERT INTO #Person (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, DomainAccountName)
VALUES (2, 'Adams', 'John', 'jadams');

INSERT INTO #Person (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, DomainAccountName)
VALUES (3, 'Jefferson', 'Thomas', 'tjefferson');

INSERT INTO #Person (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, DomainAccountName)
VALUES (4, 'Lincoln', 'Abraham', 'alincoln');

-- Load #License
INSERT INTO #License (PersonID, LicenseState, LicenseNumber, LicenseYear)
VALUES (1, 'CA', '11111', 1999);

INSERT INTO #License (PersonID, LicenseState, LicenseNumber, LicenseYear)
VALUES (2, 'CA', '22222', 2000);

INSERT INTO #License (PersonID, LicenseState, LicenseNumber, LicenseYear)
VALUES (3, 'TX', '44444', 2002);

INSERT INTO #License (PersonID, LicenseState, LicenseNumber, LicenseYear)
VALUES (3, 'OH', '33333', 2008);
```

I've tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO #License (PersonID, LicenseState, LicenseNumber, LicenseYear)
SELECT
  person.PersonID,
  srce.LicenseState,
  srce.LicenseNumber,
  srce.LicenseYear
FROM #Person person
LEFT JOIN #SourceData srce
ON person.DomainAccountName = srce.UserID
LEFT JOIN #License lic
ON person.PersonID = lic.PersonID
WHERE lic.PersonID IS NULL
  OR (lic.PersonID IS NOT NULL AND lic.LicenseState <> srce.LicenseState)
```

or

```
WHERE lic.PersonID IS NULL
  OR (lic.PersonID IS NOT NULL AND lic.LicenseState NOT IN ('CA','OH','DC','WA','IL','NY','DE','CO','HI','NJ','PA','VA','FL','TX','CT'))
```

Here's the data in #SourceData:

```
UserID      LicenseState    LicenseNumber   LicenseYear
gwashington CA              11111           1999
gwashington TX              9999            2001
jadams      CA              22222           2000
tjefferson  TX              44444           2002
alincoln    IL              55555           2012
```

Here's the data in #Person:

```
PersonID    LastName    FirstName   DomainAccountName
1           Washington  George      gwashington
2           Adams       John        jadams
3           Jefferson   Thomas      tjefferson
4           Lincoln     Abraham     alincoln
```

Here's the data in #License before the INSERT:

```
LicenseID   PersonID    LicenseState    LicenseNumber   LicenseYear
1           1           CA              11111           1999
2           2           CA              22222           2000
3           3           TX              44444           2002
4           3           OH              33333           2008
```

Here's the desired output:

```
LicenseID   PersonID    LicenseState    LicenseNumber   LicenseYear
1           1           CA              11111           1999
2           2           CA              22222           2000
3           3           TX              44444           2002
4           3           OH              33333           2008
5           1           TX              9999            2001
6           4           IL              55555           2012
```

So, gwashington & TX should be added as well as alincoln & IL. I can get alincoln & IL added but gwashington & TX doesn't.  Also, the INSERT-SELECT keeps inserting records although they've already been inserted.  It should only had new records to #License from those not already loaded from #SourceData.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Great job posting ddl and sample data but the requirements have me scratching my head.

Comment: In addition to what Sean has commented, having a desired output as a formatted table would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if thats works for you:

```
INSERT INTO #License    
SELECT p.PersonID,    
       s.LicenseState,  
       s.LicenseNumber,   
       s.LicenseYear    
FROM   #SourceData s    
       JOIN #Person p    
         ON s.UserID = p.DomainAccountName    
       LEFT JOIN #License l    
              ON l.PersonID = p.PersonID    
                 AND l.LicenseState = s.LicenseState    
WHERE  l.PersonID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  That's what I was missing.  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this, but without being able to test anything atm, a workaround might help for small/medium table sizes.

The following should give the result table as stated if I interpret the data correctly:

```
WITH BASE AS ( 
SELECT
  CONCAT(lic.PersonID, lic.LicenseState) AS IDxLicense 
  FROM #License lic
)

SELECT
  person.PersonID,
  srce.LicenseState,
  srce.LicenseNumber,
  srce.LicenseYear
FROM #Person person
LEFT JOIN #SourceData srce
ON person.DomainAccountName = srce.UserID
LEFT JOIN #License lic
ON person.PersonID = lic.PersonID 
WHERE (CONCAT(person.PersonID, srce.LicenseState) NOT IN (SELECT IDxLicense FROM BASE))
```

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't even think about using a CTE.